# Setting up Raspberry Pi 4B as a routed access point

Tags: wifi, pi-4, access-point, hostapd

Setting up Raspberry Pi 4B as a routed access point

Hi guys

I want to set up my Raspberry Pi 4B as a routed access point. Many IoT-devices in the subnetwork 192.168.7.x should connect to my RasPi over an Edimax EW-788Un Wi-Fi dongle (`wlan1`). The RasPi should connect itself to my home network over onboard Wi-Fi (`wlan0`). Here a list of the resources I have already considered:

[Simultaneously connect to a wifi network and create a wifi AP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83486/simultaneously-connect-to-a-wifi-network-and-create-a-wifi-ap)
https://github.com/garyexplains/examples/blob/master/raspberry_pi_router.md
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

Following those  guides, I have `apt-get installed` the following packages

```
dnsmasq
hostapd
```

My files are set up like so:

**DHCP**

`/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

interface wlan1
static ip_address=192.168.7.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

**dnsmasq**

/`etc/dnsmasq.conf`:

```
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=192.168.7.100,192.168.7.120,255.255.255.0,24h
domain=wlan
address=/gw.wlan/192.168.7.1
```

**IP-Forwarding**

`/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

`/etc/iptables.ipv4.nat`:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [20652:1431292]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [15820:11346033]
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

**hostapd**

`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
country_code=CH
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
ssid=swagsystem
wpa_passphrase=swagsystem
```

**PROBLEM:**

Upon start (`sudo systemctl start hostapd`) of the hostapd service, the following error occurs:

```
Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status hostapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Invoking `systemctl status hostapd.service` yelds:

```
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-06-16 14:16:19 CEST; 924ms ago
  Process: 2684 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, status=1/FAIL
```

(^^ it cut off there at the end)

`iwconfig` yields:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NalasEmpire"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: 1C:24:CD:33:35:69   
          Bit Rate=200 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:53  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`wlan1` (my Edimax dongle) was previously tuned in to the same network as `wlan0`. The setup kind of did something to it, but idk exactly what.

Does anyone see where I went wrong or what could be the problem?

**EDIT1:**

- I switched to using predictable network interfaces (found int `sudo rasp-config`). This switched my `wlan1` to wlx08beac0a717c (idk if that changed sth.)
- I put in the driver `driver=nl80211` back into hostapd (idk if that changed sth.)
- Made it run by default using `sudo update-rc.d hostapd defaults`
- I used `sudo hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` to start the daemon. This turned up an Error in the config file after which it is not allow to use less than 8 characters for the WPA passphrase. Changed that and well: it works! At least to the point that a new network now appears in my choice of available wifi-networks.

A new error appeared though:

```
wlx08beac0a717c: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
```

**Q1:** So I know that for the onboard wifi to set the country code you can do it in `raspi-config`, but how do I do it for the edimax wifi dongle?

**Q2:** I'm unsure whether to add an `/etc/network/interfaces.d/native_wifi.cfg` file. As of the moment I don't have it, but what is its use? Do I need to set the Edimax interface to static and provide a `subnetmask`? It appears in some guides, but not in all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems there is a problem to coordinate all the additional helpers. But there is an easy way to just configure the **Raspberry Pi OS** with no need to install additional programs. You can use **systemd-networkd** to do all things. It has all needed features built-in. You just configure it, what make thinks lean and well-arranged. You can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/95073/79866) how to do it.

Comment: Thank, I wish I would have stumbled upon your solution earlier! I'm kinda hesitant now to change to the other solution though as it's running quite nicely :)

Comment: @glades If the answer helped you it would be nice if you could accept it ;-) Or if you have found another solution so please write your own answer and accept it after two days. There is nothing wrong with self-answers. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Comment: "use `systemd-networkd` to do **all** things" ... ?  new car for me ?   I will have to learn more of this  :)   +1

Comment: @Seamus "to do all **networking** things ..."? Also to general? (: